# Multiplication table in JavaScript returns undefined with multiplication number WHY?

Tags: javascript

Script part:

```
function makeTable() {

    var num = document.getElementById('Numb').value;
    var myPara = document.getElementById('para');
    var tb = new Array();

    for (var i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) {

        var result = num * i;
        tb.push(result);
        tb[i] = tb[i] + "<br>";
    }

    tb = tb.join("");
    myPara.innerHTML = tb;
}
```

HTML part

```
<input type = "number" value = "" id = "Numb" placeholder = "TABLE NUMBER">
<input type = "button" value = "Give me Table" onClick = "makeTable()">
<p align = "center" name = "myownpara" id = "para"> </p>
```

When I run this code it returns undefined with first element of array

Comment: Array indexes start at 0, not 1

Comment: but tell me how to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays start at 0, not 1. Change it to `var i= 0` in your 'for' loop and add the line `if(i==0) continue;` right after starting your for loop to skip over 0.

Actually, another problem is your array. It might be best to initialise your 0th element because you are looking at it later. Change `new Array()` to `new Array(""):` To already add a 0th element so you dont have to when you use my aforementioned `continue` statement.

### Update, refinement

I refined your code below. I don't know why you are using an array, as you want to output a string anyway. So Just add it to the string for every element as it reduces the amount of things you need to do. The below will work. I also removed you 'myPara' as you only use it once anyway, so theres no point in saving it.

Also note that in this case we don't need to start at 0 as we don't have an array to add to.

```
function makeTable() {

    var num = document.getElementById('Numb').value;

    // lets use a string since thats what you want in the end and its easier.
    var tb = "";

    for (var i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) {
        // add it to the string. I reduced the number of steps as its so simple
        // You don't need to save stuff in vars for this thing.
        tb += (num * i) + "<br>";
    }

    document.getElementById('para') = tb;
}
```

Comment: @Avinsash Kumar If you used the `continue` statement as I said it should not have been added at all. However, I added a refinement that reduces your code complexity and does the same thing.

Comment: actually i wanted this you made but when it not works i used array, i find it more easier for me and also i can use it for future programming

Comment: Could you mark it as correct if it answered your question? Cheers

Comment: Sorry didnt see your second answer before posting my comment - you should do this only case-by-case. If you need a string, use a string. If you want an array, use an array but read our comments and read up on arrays as they are versatile but a bit more complex, and not suited for this specific purpose.